# How to compile php and curl-extension with custom version libcurl?

Tags: linux, php, curl, compilation

I want compile `php-5.6.15` with custom version of `libcurl`. Why? There was a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988782/curl-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-error-in-server-but-works-on-lo/21022319#21022319) with `curl` which makes some https requests failed. My distro's repositories contains just version with bug. So I guess I need to make such steps as:

- compile `curl` dependencies(`libssl`)
- compile `curl` with those dependencies
- compile `php` with custom `curl`

My main problem is that I'm not allowed to use package manager and need to specify custom build directory, custom directory for dependencies, and so on and so forth.

So the question is: how I can achieve this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: "Not allowed" to use the package manager?  Why not?

Comment: Cause if I try to use another `curl` version I'll get a lot of dependencies issues. For example: I want `curl-7.28`, but `git`,`python3-pycurl`,`apt-transport-https`, etc. depends on current `7.35` version.

Comment: [`curl`'s latest version is 7.45](http://curl.haxx.se/), but at any rate, [`libcurl`'s ABI hasn't changed since 2006](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/features.html#stableapi), so if your package manager isn't capable of handling that, you've got to re-consider your technology choices.

Comment: Oh, I'm thinking about virtual machine just for developing(without any GUI, X-server), but it makes developing process a little bit complicated. So I'd like to deal with this problem on my machine. But if it too difficult, I'll look for the virtual machine with another distro.